# How to make WordPress blog accessible for people with disabilities?

Tags: accessibility

How do you make your wordpress blog accessible for people with disabilities  ?

are there any special plugins you are using ? 
are there any friendly themes you recommend ? 
is there an auto-detect in the browser if the operating system accessibility tools are running ? aka is there a way to build an auto-detect that will load a special theme onces accessibility tools are enabled.

thanks for the help and suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Codex has some info on it overall:

- [Accessibility](http://codex.wordpress.org/Accessibility)
- [WordPress ATAG Evaluation](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_ATAG_Evaluation)

Comment: I went thru many documents and checked the guidlines - i am looking more for a list of prefered plugins to use based on user recommendation